# Separating clusters by a line

Tags: python

I have a data set which consists of several clusters. I want to separate these clusters with a line, just like a Voronoi diagram but then not created from one dot. The idea I have now is to determine the shortest distance between each point and find the points which are on the outside of the cluster. The average distance needs to be taken, to determine the line separating the clusters.

The closest point can be determined via cdist. I want to loop over each cluster and compare each point in the cluster to the other points in the other clusters. However, I'm stuck at doing this. Below you can find my code written in Python.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def closest_point(pt, others):
    distances = cdist(pt, others)
    return others[distances.argmin()]

ppx = [[615, 618, 621], [629, 623, 620, 625], [614, 622, 610, 612]]
ppy = [[524, 530, 527], [559, 556, 548, 548], [559, 574, 572, 542]]

for i in range(0,3): # range(len(grouped))
    for j in range(len(ppx[i])):
        a = [[ppx[i][j], ppy[i][j]]]
        others = ..??..
        print("closest:", closest_point(a, others))

    plt.scatter(ppx[i],ppy[i])
plt.show()
```

As you can see I can I can find that one point in the cluster (**a**), however, I get stuck when I want to put the other two clusters in **others**. Has anyone an idea how to solve this issue? Or am I thinking in the wrong direction?

I added a picture with three clusters and the separation line I intend to make.

[image]